# Access Objects inside function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, oop

Im new to javascript and i need some guidance here.

```
"use strict";
(function() {

var maxHeightCalc = {
    $maxHeight : 23,
    $childElem : $(".equalHeights .section").length,
    init : function() {

        console.log(maxHeightCalc.$maxHeight); //prints 23
        console.log(maxHeightCalc.$childElem); // prints undefined

        for (var i=0; i<maxHeightCalc.$childElem.length; i++) {
            console.log(i);
        }
    }
};
$(function(){
    maxHeightCalc.init();
})

})(window);
```

HTML structure

```
<body>
    <div class="equalHeights">
        <h1>Equal heights with OOJS </h1>
        <div class="section section-1">
            <h2>Section 1 </h2>
            <p> 
                Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. 

            </p>
        </div>

        <div class="section section-2">
            <h2>Section 2 </h2>
            <p> 
                Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. 
                remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing 
                Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of 
                Lorem Ipsum.
            </p>
        </div>

        <div class="section section-3">
            <h2>Section 3 </h2>
            <p> 
                Lorem Ipsum i
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

I have two objects $maxHeight and $childElem. im trying to access both object inside the init function. Im getting value for $maxHeight, but for $childElem the value is undefined. Can some one please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show the html as well?

Comment: This code works. If I just run it in my console, it prints `23` and `0`, and then `undefined`, but it is expected, as the function does not return anything, so the return value is undefined.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. If you see my html, $(".equalHeights .section").length have to return 3, but right now its returning 0, this the problem which im facing

Comment: Will only work if script shown is at bottom of body tag otherwise `$(".equalHeights .section")` don't exist when you set `$childElem`. Could set `$childElem` inside `init()` since it is being called after document is ready

Comment: Thanks, its working fine after placing the script file after body tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bet is that, because `$(".equalHeights .section").length` is called on object creation which probably does not wait for the DOM to be created, HTML is not yet available so elements are not found.

So, either wrap all your code into `$(function () { ... })` so that DOM is done on function execution (you can thus probably get rid of the IIFE), or make `init` function launch the jQuery element selection.